# Sierra: .bash_profile not being sourced

Tags: bash, macos, visual-studio-code, macos-high-sierra

Trying to add 'code' to my path, and I noticed I had to make a new ~/.bash_profile in my home directory.

I added the path export for code, and now i'm trying to link it, since 'code' is still unrecognized in a new terminal.

Did I add it to the right place? I'm still not sure why I had to make a brand new bash_profile.
If so, what do I do to link it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.bashrc` you can add an alias for starting vscode. To do that add the following code in `.bashrc`:

```
alias code="path/to/code"
```

where `path/to/code` should be replaced by the path you have in your system for vscode.

Then source the `.bashrc`, in terminal type this:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Sourcing is very important once you modify `.bashrc`, without this your changes won't be used.